# Scrolling in Android

Tags: android

In my project I want to use scrolling for rendering the pdf in landscape mode.
I have used onscroll method in Android, but when I run the application on a Samsung Galaxy device the scrolling is not smooth.
Can anybody suggest how to get fine and smooth scrolling, and are there any methods other than onscroll?

Comment: can u post your onScroll method here?

Answer (score 1):

To get smooth scrolling of a complex image, try caching it to an offscreen bitmap. The trick to minimize memory usage is to only cache a little bit beyond the visible view bounds, and regenerate the cache as the user scrolls.

For sample code, see https://github.com/ldo/view_cache_demo_android